# Dropdown com valor "default" e opção "todos"

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2

Utilizando o CakePHP no meu projeto, eu criei um *dropdown* para usar para pesquisar no banco de dados por valores e *strings*.

Eu preciso criar uma opção "todos" para procurar todos os resultados e para ser a opção "default" desse *dropdown*. Como posso fazer isso?

Código:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('RegistroHorario', array('class' => 'form-horizontal bucket-form', 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>  
<div class="col-lg-3">  
<?php echo $this->Form->select('RegistroHorario.cliente_id', $clientes, array('empty' => false ,'div' => false,'label'=>false, 'class' => 'form-control m-bot15', 'width' => '10'));?>  
</div><div class="col-lg-3">  
<?php echo $this->Form->select('RegistroHorario.user_id', $usuarios, array('empty' => false ,'div' => false,'label'=>false, 'class' => 'form-control m-bot15', 'width' => '10'));?>   
</div>  
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Buscar" />  
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No controller, você faz uma verificação se o método é `POST`. Quando não for, você define o valor diretamente na propriedade `data`do controller  do Cakephp.

Veja:

```
<?php
    if ($this->Request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        // Operação para salvar os dados no banco
    } else {
        $this->data['RegistroHorario']['campo_select'] = "valor igual ao quer que seja o Default";
    }
```

Essa vista no [SO inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222836/cakephp-setting-default-value-on-a-select-with-optgroups).

**Atualização**

Como há também a necessidade de acrescentar "todos" ao select, creio que, se é passada uma variável do tipo `Array` para preencher os `option` do `select`, então bastaria você fazer assim:

```
$this->Form->select('RegistroHorario.usuario_id', array('valor' => 'Todos') + $usuarios)
```

Comment: Mas no dropdown aparecem as informações do banco, eu queria que mostrasse o campo "Todos" também, e que ele viesse como default

Comment: Fiz a atualização da resposta. Creio que isso já deva resolver o problema.

Comment: Deu certo, consegui, Valeu. Tentei marcar como útil, porém preciso de 15 pontos de reputação :/ quando eu atingir tento novamente marcá-la.